# How to change text into a div using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

why this code resets all the page if i wrote that the only one div've to be changed is #text.
I added jquery from google api. I changed this but seems that's not the problem.
I used also javascript doing the text update, but the other div disappeared.
Can't understanding.

This the code with problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>F++</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickme").on("click", function(event) {
        $("div#text").text("clicked");
    });
});
</script>  
</head>

<body style="margin:0 auto; padding:0 auto,">
<div id="bodycontent" style="background-color:#aaaaaa; width:100%;">

<div id="text" style="background-color:#aaaaaa; width:100%;">
Noclick
<div>

<div id="clickme" style="width:1000px; height:1000px; display: table; margin: 0 auto; border: 0px;">clickme</div>

</div><!-- /bodycontent -->
</body>
</html>
```

here the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/osj1phct/

thank you.

me now -> XD

Comment: It's always a shame when someone goes to the trouble of digging through a questioner's code to find a mistake, and then the questioner posts their own answer with the same solution instead of choosing the answer by the person who helped.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the problem!!!

```
<div id="text" style="background-color:#aaaaaa; width:100%;">
Noclick
<div>   <!-- was here -->
```

i omitted a slash on the closure tag

Here the good code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>F++</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickme").on("click", function(event) {
        $("div#text").text("Clicked");
    });
});
</script>  
</head>

<body style="margin:0 auto; padding:0 auto,">
<div id="bodycontent" style="background-color:#aaaaaa; width:100%;">

<div id="text" style="background-color:#aaaaaa; width:100%; text-align:center;">Unclicked</div>



<br>
<button id="clickme" style="width:100%; height:100px; display:block; margin: 0 auto; border: 0px;">Clickme</button>

</div><!-- /bodycontent -->
</body>
</html>
```

And the good fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Lmq14otf/

excuse me!

(thanks also to Jorge Piquer)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the backslash on the closing div for #text. Should be `</div>` after "Noclick"

Comment: 'You forgot the backslash on the closing div for #text. Should be </div> after "Noclick"' oOOOOOOPS!